# How fill missing values in df with grouped median and mode values from another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan, missing-data

I am novice in python. I am trying to fill missing values in a dataframe with grouped median for numeric types and grouped mode for category type columns with the below code on a dataset.

```
##categoriestypes = list of category columns
 for col in categoriestypes:
         dataset[col]= dataset.groupby(['A', 'B'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))       

##numerictypes = list of numeric columns  
 for col in numerictypes:
        dataset[col]= dataset.groupby(['B', 'C])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

This works as expected and fill the missing values of each column with median/mode as per the groupby condition.

How can i save these median and mode for all columns with groupby and use the same values to fill missing values on a different dataset? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a reproducible sample dataset

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to inverted comma to store the results into a column, i.e.,`dataset['col']` .

```
for col in categoriestypes:
         dataset['col']= dataset.groupby(['A', 'B'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))
```

Now, that you have multiple columns and need to store all the columns into the data frame. So, you will have to create the columns dynamically.

Here is how to use `.format()` to do it:

for col in categoriestypes:
df['{}_mode'.format(col)]= dataset.groupby(['A', 'B'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))

or if you want a numeric value after the original column name to rename/name the newly created column you can use `enumerate` to get the index of the list or you can also generate random numbers using a another for loop.

```
for i, col in enumerate(categoriestypes):
    df['{}_mode''{}'.format(col,i)]= df.groupby(['A'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[3,10,6,7]])
y = np.array([[1,9,4],[2,4,np]])
df1=pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, size=(16, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df1.A=pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x, 3))
df1.B=pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x, 2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         
        "E": ["foo", "bar", "foo", np.nan, "foo", np.nan, np.nan, "foo","foo", "bar", "foo", np.nan, "foo", np.nan, np.nan, "foo"],
        "F": ["one", "one", "two", "three", "two", "two", "one", "three","one", "one", "two", "three", "two", "two", "one", "three"],
        "G": np.random.randn(16),
        "H": np.random.randn(16),
    }
)

df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
##categoriestypes = list of category columns
categoriestypes=['E','F']
numerictypes=['D','G','H']


for col in categoriestypes:
    df['{}_mode'.format(col)]= df.groupby(['A'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))
  

for i, col in enumerate(numerictypes):
    df['{}_mode''{}'.format(col,i)]= df.groupby(['B', 'C'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

original df:

```
 df: 
     A   B   C   D    E      F         G         H
0    1   1  88  74  foo    one  1.764052  1.494079
1    1   1  88  47  bar    one  0.400157 -0.205158
2    1   2   3  98  foo    two  0.978738  0.313068
3    2   2  30  44  NaN  three  2.240893 -0.854096
4    2   3  94  99  foo    two  1.867558 -2.552990
5    2   3  79   2  NaN    two -0.977278  0.653619
6    3   4  55  54  NaN    one  0.950088  0.864436
7    3   4  40  39  foo  three -0.151357 -0.742165
8    3   3  13  83  foo    one -0.103219  2.269755
9    4   3  52  74  bar    one  0.410599 -1.454366
10   4  10  99  16  foo    two  0.144044  0.045759
11   4  10  27  59  NaN  three  1.454274 -0.187184
12   3   6  73  81  foo    two  0.761038  1.532779
13   3   6  10  76  NaN    two  0.121675  1.469359
14   3   7  74  40  NaN    one  0.443863  0.154947
15  10   7  15  20  foo  three  0.333674  0.378163
```

`df` after doing the `lambda` operation:

```
df:

     A   B   C   D    E      F         G         H E_mode F_mode  D_mode0   G_mode1   H_mode2
0    1   1  10  34  foo    one  1.764052  1.494079    foo    one       34  1.764052  1.494079
1    1   1  21  35  bar    one  0.400157 -0.205158    bar    one       35  0.400157 -0.205158
2    1   2  17   2  foo    two  0.978738  0.313068    foo    two        2  0.978738  0.313068
3    2   2  70  41  NaN  three  2.240893 -0.854096    foo  three       41  2.240893 -0.854096
4    2   3   2  43  foo    two  1.867558 -2.552990    foo    two       43  1.867558 -2.552990
5    2   3   5   9  NaN    two -0.977278  0.653619    foo    two        9 -0.977278  0.653619
6    3   4  38  85  NaN    one  0.950088  0.864436    foo    one       85  0.950088  0.864436
7    3   4  82  58  foo  three -0.151357 -0.742165    foo  three       58 -0.151357 -0.742165
8    3   3  93  62  foo    one -0.103219  2.269755    foo    one       62 -0.103219  2.269755
9    4   3  98  86  bar    one  0.410599 -1.454366    bar    one       86  0.410599 -1.454366
10   4  10  57  25  foo    two  0.144044  0.045759    foo    two       25  0.144044  0.045759
11   4  10  12  70  NaN  three  1.454274 -0.187184    bar  three       70  1.454274 -0.187184
12   3   6  65  79  foo    two  0.761038  1.532779    foo    two       79  0.761038  1.532779
13   3   6  12  45  NaN    two  0.121675  1.469359    foo    two       45  0.121675  1.469359
14   3   7  69  10  NaN    one  0.443863  0.154947    foo    one       10  0.443863  0.154947
15  10   7  31  45  foo  three  0.333674  0.378163    foo  three       45  0.333674  0.378163
```

Comment: I think i couldn't make the problem clear. I need to calculate and store the  grouped, mean for numeric columns and grouped mode for catgeorical type for each column on dataset1.  On a different dataset2, if there exists missing values, they need to be filled as per the corresponding groupby column values calculated on dataset1.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a minimal, reproducible example? To begin to help, we'll need a concrete example of your DataFrame (as text, not images) and also your desired DataFrames df1 and df2.